# Cron to run every 4 hours with different name then overwrite, MySQL db

Tags: mysql, unix, cron

I want to run a cron job every hours hours to back up my mysql database.

When it has run for 24 hours I want it to start again and then overwrite each file.

The best I have come up with is:

```
15 0 * * * /usr/bin/mysqldump -u DBUSERNAME -pDBPASSWORD DBNAME > /PATH/backup1.sql
15 4 * * * /usr/bin/mysqldump -u DBUSERNAME -pDBPASSWORD DBNAME > /PATH/backup2.sql
15 8 * * * /usr/bin/mysqldump -u DBUSERNAME -pDBPASSWORD DBNAME > /PATH/backup3.sql
15 12 * * * /usr/bin/mysqldump -u DBUSERNAME -pDBPASSWORD DBNAME > /PATH/backup4.sql
15 16 * * * /usr/bin/mysqldump -u DBUSERNAME -pDBPASSWORD DBNAME > /PATH/backup5.sql
15 20 * * * /usr/bin/mysqldump -u DBUSERNAME -pDBPASSWORD DBNAME > /PATH/backup6.sql
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this and do cron jobs auto overwrite a file or is there a switch I need to add?

New to server stuff but gotta learn!

Comment: You also might want to take a read of [Establishing a Backup Policy](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/backup-policy.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for something like:

```
15 */4 * * * /bin/bash /path/to/your/script.sh
```

This executes `/bin/bash /path/to/your/script.sh` every 4 hours at minute 15.

And then let `script.sh` be:

```
num=$(( ($(date "+%H") + 4 ) / 4))
/usr/bin/mysqldump -u DBUSERNAME -pDBPASSWORD DBNAME > /PATH/backup${num}.sql
```

To get

```
hour    num
 0       1
 4       2
 ....
20       6
```

I use:

- `$(date "+%H")` returns the hour.
- `$(date "+%H") + 4` returns the hour +4.
- `$(( ($(date "+%H") + 4 ) / 4))` returns the hour +4 divided by 4.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply rotate your backups before actual backup.

```
#!/bin/sh

for I in `jot 5 5 1`; do
  NN=`expr $I + 1`
  mv backup$I.sql backup$NN.sql
done
mysqldump -u DBUSERNAME -pDBPASSWORD DBNAME > backup1.sql
```